# How do I configure Camunda Applications (Tasklist/Cockpit/Admin) to a User?

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I have created a Camunda spring-boot application by adding the following dependencies with 3.4.2 version by pointing to default h2 database.

`<artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-ee</artifactId>
<artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>`

1. I am able to start the application and able to access the Web Applications Cockpit/Tasklist/Admin.
2. I have created a user (demotasklist) by giving access to tasklist under Application Authorization section with the help of demo (default camunda-admin) user.
3. When I try to login with demotasklist user into the camunda web application, am able to access all 3 applications (Cockpit/Tasklist/Admin), instead of only Tasklist application.

Is there any special configuratio required under spring-boot application to see only Tasklist application by login with demotasklist user?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to access only the camunda Tasklist / Admin / Cockpit applications individually by enabling the Authorization under application properties.

`camunda.bpm.authorization.enabled=true`

OR

`camunda:
  bpm:
    authorization:
      enabled:  true`